# PySpark column wise bind

Tags: pyspark

Is there any specific way in PySpark to cbind two data frames as we do cbind in r?

Example:

1. Data frame 1 has 10 columns
2. Data frame 2 has 1 column

I need to cbind both the data frame and make as one data frame in PySpark.

Answer (score 2):

First let's create our dataframes:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([10*[c] for c in range(10)]), ["c"+ str(i) for i in range(10)])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([[c] for c in range(10, 20, 1)]), ["c10"])
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    | c0| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6| c7| c8| c9|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
    |  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|
    |  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|
    |  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|
    |  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|
    |  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|
    |  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|
    |  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|
    |  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|
    |  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

    +---+
    |c10|
    +---+
    | 10|
    | 11|
    | 12|
    | 13|
    | 14|
    | 15|
    | 16|
    | 17|
    | 18|
    | 19|
    +---+
```

Then we want to identify rows uniquely, there is a function for `RDD` that can do this `zipWithIndex`

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
from pyspark.sql import Row
def zipindexdf(df):
    schema_new = df.schema.add("index", LongType(), False)
    return df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda l: list(l[0]) + [l[1]]).toDF(schema_new)

df1_index = zipindexdf(df1)
df1_index.show()
df2_index = zipindexdf(df2)
df2_index.show()

    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
    | c0| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6| c7| c8| c9|index|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
    |  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|    0|
    |  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|    1|
    |  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|    2|
    |  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|    3|
    |  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|    4|
    |  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|    5|
    |  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|    6|
    |  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|    7|
    |  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|    8|
    |  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|    9|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+

    +---+-----+
    |c10|index|
    +---+-----+
    | 10|    0|
    | 11|    1|
    | 12|    2|
    | 13|    3|
    | 14|    4|
    | 15|    5|
    | 16|    6|
    | 17|    7|
    | 18|    8|
    | 19|    9|
    +---+-----+
```

Finally, we can join them:

```py
df = df1_index.join(df2_index, "index", "inner")

    +-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |index| c0| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6| c7| c8| c9|c10|
    +-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |    0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0| 10|
    |    7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7|  7| 17|
    |    6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6|  6| 16|
    |    9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9|  9| 19|
    |    5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5|  5| 15|
    |    1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1| 11|
    |    3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3|  3| 13|
    |    8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8|  8| 18|
    |    2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2|  2| 12|
    |    4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4|  4| 14|
    +-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: This does not work for two separate large DataFrames that may be stored across different partitions and each DataFrame is separated between partitions on different rows.  From the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) ***"The current implementation puts the partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each partition in the lower 33 bits."***

Comment: You're right, I can't believe I wrote that... The count of `MonotonicallyIncreasingID` has a different origin with every task

Comment: The oft cited rdd function `zipwithindex` works the same way.

Comment: `zipWithIndex` is the indicated way to enumerate rows. Using a window function on the whole data frame is terribly inefficient. I encourage you to test it and use %timeit.

Comment: Now you're right.  `zipWithIndex` does not work the same way.  I will amend my answer.  However, because the window function is lazily evaluated, it is not as straight forward to test the timing.  I suppose I could get the time to `show()` the DataFrame with an equivalent `.filter()` before and after the column created by the window function was added to the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

To get a column with IDs that are monotonically increasing, unique ***and*** consecutive, use the following on each of your DataFrames, where `colName` is the column name you want to sort each DataFrame by.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W

window = (
    W.partitionBy(F.lit(0))
    .orderBy('colName')
    .rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.currentRow)
)

df = (df
 .withColumn('int', F.lit(1))
 .withColumn('consec_id', F.sum('int').over(window))
 .drop('int')
)
```

To check that everything is lining up correctly, use the following code to look at the tail, or last `rownums` of the DataFrame.

```
rownums = 10
df.where(F.col('consec_id')>df.count()-rownums).show()
```

Use the following code to look at the rows from `start_row` to `end_row` of the DataFrame.

```
start_row = 20
end_row = 30
df.where((F.col('consec_id')>start_row) & (F.col('consec_id')<end_row)).show()
```

#Update

Another method that works is the RDD method `zipWithIndex()`.  To simply amend the existing DataFrame with a column of consecutive id's using this RDD method, I:

1. converted the df to RDD,
2. applied the `zipWithIndex()` method,
3. converted the returned RDD to a DataFrame,
4. converted the DataFrame to an RDD,
5. mapped an RDD lambda function to combine the RDD row object of the original DataFrame with the indexes,
6. converted the final RDD to a DataFrame with the original column names + an ID column from the integers created by `zipWithIndex()`.

I also tried the method of amending the original DataFrame with an index column containing the output of `zipWithIndex()` similar to what @MaFF did, but the results were even slower.  The window function is around an order of magnitude faster than either of these.  Most of this time increase appears to be from converting the DataFrame to RDD and back again.

Please let me know if there is a faster way to add the output of the `zipWithIndex()` RDD method as a column in the original DataFrame.

Testing on a 42,000 row 90 column DataFrame yields the following.

```
import time

def test_zip(df):
  startTime = time.time()
  df_1 = df \
  .rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF() \
  .rdd.map(lambda row: (row._1) + (row._2,)) \
  .toDF(df.columns + ['consec_id'])

  start_row = 20000
  end_row = 20010
  df_1.where((F.col('consec_id')>start_row) & (F.col('consec_id')<end_row)).show()
  endTime = time.time() - startTime
  return str(round(endTime,3)) + " seconds"

[test_zip(df) for _ in range(5)]
```

['59.813 seconds',
'39.574 seconds',
'36.074 seconds',
'35.436 seconds',
'35.636 seconds']

```
import time
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W

def test_win(df):
  startTime = time.time()
  window = W.orderBy('colName').rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.currentRow)
  df_2 = df \
  .withColumn('int', F.lit(1)) \
  .withColumn('IDcol', F.sum('int').over(window)) \
  .drop('int')

  start_row = 20000
  end_row = 20010
  df_2.where((F.col('consec_id')>start_row) & (F.col('consec_id')<end_row)).show()
  endTime = time.time() - startTime
  return str(round(endTime,3)) + " seconds"  

[test_win(df) for _ in range(5)]
```

['4.19 seconds',
'4.508 seconds',
'4.099 seconds',
'4.012 seconds',
'4.045 seconds']

```
import time
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField
import pyspark.sql.types as T

def test_zip2(df):
  startTime = time.time()
  schema_new = StructType(list(df.schema) + [StructField("consec_id", T.LongType(), False)])
  df_3 = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda l: list(l[0]) + [l[1]]).toDF(schema_new)

  start_row = 20000
  end_row = 20010
  df_3.where((F.col('IDcol')>start_row) & (F.col('consec_id')<end_row)).show()
  endTime = time.time() - startTime
  return str(round(endTime,3)) + " seconds"

[test_zip2(testdf) for _ in range(5)]
```

['82.795 seconds',
'61.689 seconds',
'58.181 seconds',
'58.01 seconds',
'57.765 seconds']